# Always use my; never use local?

Tags: perl, variables

Implementing dynamic scoping, I was using **[`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html)**. Then I came across **[this](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html)** post, which says the following:

> Why have local at all? The answer is 90% history. Early versions of
>   Perl only had global variables. local was very easy to implement, and
>   was added to Perl 4 as a partial solution to the local variable
>   problem.

**...never use local.**

Is its use deprecated, or discouraged? If yes, what is the alternative?

Comment: Post you linked to isn't wrong about. But the statement **...never use local** is. Retaining value between function calls is one of the advantage of `local`. When you use `my`, you do lexical scoping, which means it is only valid between curly braces of that block and not between function calls. Use my when you want separate values with every call. `local` is for reusing global variables as brand new variables for that block only.

Comment: @Drt: `local` variables *don't* retain their values across function calls.

Comment: @borodin: from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29): `local is mostly used when the current value of a variable must be visible to called subroutines.`

Comment: @Drt: I wouldn't call that "retaining a value between function calls", which implies that the variable is static and will be unchanged from one call to the next *of the same subroutine*. `my` variables also retain their values across calls to nested subroutines - they just aren't necessarily accessible from those subroutines.

Comment: @Borodin So "retaining a value between function calls" will mean keeping the last changed value.

Comment: @Drt: and that's what `local` doesn't do. I'm not sure whether you understand this or not, and I don't see how that Wikipiedia entry is relevant as `local` values aren't saved on the call stack. If I write a subroutine that declares and modifies a `local` variable, and then calls that subroutine twice, the last value of that variable won't be remembered from the first call.

Comment: @Borodin - I think **it does**. `#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
{
local $a=10;
reassign();
reassign();
}

sub reassign{
        print $a;
        $a=20;
}
` This snippet of code works for me. And from this I get that `local` is retaining value. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Drt It will keep its value till the closing brace of the current scope. I think you are correct here. However, a **package variable** if made local would retain value within that scope *only*, and would revert to its old value, at the closing of the scope. I think this is what Borodin means. Seen with `#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 

$a = 5;
{ 
local $a=10; 
reassign(); 
reassign(); 
} 
reassign(); 

sub reassign{ 
 print $a; 
 $a=20; 
}`

Comment: @Cthulhu - You are right about scope, but I am confused and puzzled about both statements about `local` and `my` from Borodin. *my variables also retain their values across calls to nested subroutines*. This statement is also confusing and wrong(in my view). If you make variable in the code I added as `my`. It gives you error as `Use of uninitialized value in print`.

Comment: `my variables also retain their values across calls to nested subroutines`. It "exists" on the call-stack, but isn't accessible to nested subroutines.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The post you linked to is misleading, or at least incomplete.  It is true that you should never use `local` to create a lexical variable.  It doesn't do so, and that is what `my` is for.

However, you *should* use `local` when you need its actual functionality: giving a temporary value to a global variable.  This is most often used for temporarily setting Perl's special variables.  A classic case is something like this:

```
{
    local $/;
    $entire_file = <$filehandle>;
}
```

In order to read an entire file at once, you need to set the record separator to undefined.  But you only want to do that temporarily; hence `local` should be used.

This is absolutely not discouraged.  It is considered good Perl code.

**Update:** I see that the article actually has a note which qualifies its "never use local" statement.  Still, I think it is misleading to make such a blanket statement. I agree with the critics to which the note is responding.  The example above is quite a common, basic case, and there are several other common uses of `local` in that vein, as well.

I understand that a beginners' tutorial needs to keep things simple, but simple doesn't have to mean inaccurate.  *"For now, don't worry about `local`; just use `my`"* would be just as clear and simple, but wouldn't  mislead someone into thinking that local should *never* be used.

Comment: +1 I agree. The localization mechanism, *scoped, push-down values*. Is an important part of what makes Perl Perl (expressive). If it wasn't for backward compatibility, we could *still* use fewer variables like this--and that would increase the rarity even further. I think the best point that can be made in this vein is that if you are confused about whether to use `local` or `my`, you probably want--or should want--a *lexical*, and you probably should use `my`. Even if only 1% of the cases warrant another approach, that 1% more than "never".

Answer (score 5):

Use `my` to create a local variable, which is most of the time what people want.

It's fine to use `local` for the thing that only `local` does: setting a different value to a global variable, which will be restored after the current block. That is in no way deprecated. It's stable, well-supported, and is a key Perl feature. (However, it happens not to be something people tend to want any where near as often as creating a local variable. In particular many beginners never need to do this.)

What is discouraged is using `local` to attempt to create a local variable, because that's what `my` should be used for. There is never any reason to use `local` for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad advice, actually.  As with all programming dicta, the unspoken addendum is ["unless you really know what you're doing"](http://senseis.xmp.net/?ProverbsDoNotApplyToWhite).  There are legitimate use cases for `local`.  But in general, if you think `local` is the right tool, you should reconsider before proceeding.