# how to call single perl script to run parallely through loop for different input parameters

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I am new in perl. currently i am running a perl scripts which will call another perl script. the second perl script is having 2 input parameters

```
sample2.pl -itest.txt -ffile1.txt
```

I have different input parameters for `-f` like `file1,file2,file3...file10`.

Now i want to run the second perl script parallel for all the input parameters(file1,file2,file3)
currently i m running as -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

use strict;

my $fi="output3.txt";--(output3.txt will contain the files file1,file2..file10)
    open (OF, $fi);

foreach(<OF>)
{
system ("perl ucm3.pl -iinput.txt -f$_ ");

print $_;
}
```

But it is not runnng parallely it is running one after the other. PLease help to run these script parallely.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new process and detach it from your main program. You could do this on foot [with `fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html), but you could also do this with [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager). It will take care of everything for you.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);

open (my $fh, '<', "output3.txt") or die $!;
while (my $data = <$fh>) {
  chomp $data;

  # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
  my $pid = $pm->start and next;

  # we are now in the child process
  print system ("perl ucm3.pl -iinput.txt -f$data ");

  $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
```

**Edit**: If you are not yet familiar with Perl, take a look at [this manual](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html). It will tell you how to get Parallel::FormManager (and other things) from CPAN.

Comment: hi..i used the above solution to run the scripts parellely. it working but the performance is not improved that much. actually ucm3.pl is used to scan the huge directory structure and so it is taking much time to run. Can u please suggest some better way to improve the performance.

Comment: @Dhiraj Please ask a new question for that, as it is kind of unrelated. Add some of the code of ucm3.pl for the scanning, and explain what parts of your directory structure you are scanning. We'll find a solution then.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. I have raised a new question for this "How to improve perl script performance?"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good answers given, you should consider a redesign so that you don't use `system` to start a new instance of Perl with each process.

Starting all of these `perl`s will add overhead (and that is probably something you care about if you are trying to speed things up with parallel processing).

Ideally, you would make ucm3.pl into a module that can be called from your main program.

But for a quick hack solution, you could just wrap the whole file in a subroutine call:

```
sub ucm3
{
    #a trick to make the sub arguments look like program arguments.
    local @ARGV = @_;

    [ rest of the ucm3.pl file in here. ]

}
```

Now, in your program, include the file:

```
require 'ucm3.pl';
```

And instead of your system call, you can do this:

```
ucm3("-iinput.txt", "-f$_");
```

Combine with `fork` or `threads` as suggested in the other answers.

**Update:** since you are using the same "input.txt" file every time, you could probably make further efficiency gains by refactoring the code so that "input.txt" is only processed once.  This would be especially true if that file is large.

Comment: Thanks.  Incidentally, it also demonstrates another valid use of local. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14458072/1919238

Answer (score 0):

For parallel processing you can use `threads`.
The documentation can be studied [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Unix like system, you will be able to do a system call where you place an & at the end of the system command:

```
system "perl ucm3.pl -iinput.txt -f$_ &"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with threads and Thread::Queue. It's a little more verbose than Parallel::ForkManager but it's easy to manage and can easily be modified to capture all the outputs and pass them off to another queue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use contant MAX_THREADS => 10;

# create a queue that we will fill with work
my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

open (my $fh, '<', "output3.txt") or die "cannot open output3.txt $!";
while (my $data = <$fh>) {
  chomp $data;
  # add each file to the queue
  $q->enqueue($data);
}

for (1..MAX_THREADS) {
  # create some faux signals to end work
  $q->enqueue("SIGEXIT");
  # create threads and do work
  threads->create("work");
}

# wait until threads are all done
while (threads->list(threads::running)) {
  sleep 1;
}
print "all done\n";

# subroutine each thread performs
sub work {
  while (my $file = $q->dequeue()) {
    last if $file eq 'SIGEXIT';
    print system ("perl ucm3.pl -iinput.txt -f$file");
  }
  # detach thread for automatic cleanup
  threads->detach;
}
```