# How to improve perl script performance?

Tags: performance, perl, parallel-processing

I am running the ucm2.pl script to scan a huge directory structure (directory is a network drive mapped to local). I have two perl scripts ucm1.pl and ucm2.pl. I am running ucm2.pl parellely for different arguments and it is called through ucm1.pl.

ucm1.pl -

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict; 
    use warnings;
    use Parallel::ForkManager;

    my $filename ="intfSplitList.txt"; #(this will have list of all the input files. eg intfSplit_0....intfSplit_50)
     my $lines;
     my $buffer;
        open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can't open `$filename': $!";
        while (<FILE>) {
            $lines = $.;
        }
        close FILE;
    print "The number of lines in $filename is $lines \n";


    my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($lines); #(it will set the no. of parallel processes)

    open (my $fh, '<', "intfSplitList.txt") or die $!;
    while (my $data = <$fh>) {
      chomp $data;

      my $pid = $pm->start and next;

     system ("perl ucm2.pl -iinput.txt -f$data");  
#(call the ucm2.pl) #(input.txt file will have search keyword and $data will have intfSplit_*.txt files)

      $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
    }
```

ucm2.pl code-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;  
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Std;
#getting the input parameters
getopts('i:f:');

our($opt_i, $opt_f);
my $searchKeyword     = $opt_i;                               #Search keyword file.
my $intfSplit         = $opt_f;                               #split file
my $path              = "Z:/aims/";                           #source directory
my $searchString;                                             #search keyword

open FH, ">log.txt";                                          #open the log file to write

print FH "$intfSplit ". "started at ".(localtime)."\n";       #write the log file

open (FILE,$intfSplit);                                       #open the split file to read

while(<FILE>){

   my $intf= $_;                                             #setting the interface to intf
   chomp($intf);
   my $dir = $path.$intf;
   chomp($dir);
   print "$dir \n";                                              
   open(INP,$searchKeyword);                         #open the search keyword file to read

   while (<INP>){      

   $searchString =$_;                           #setting the search keyword to searchString
   chomp($searchString);
   print "$searchString \n";
   open my $out, ">", "vob$intfSplit.txt" or die $!; #open the vobintfSplit_* file to write

#calling subroutine printFile to find and print the path of element
find(\&printFile,$dir);                                       

#the subroutine will search for the keyword and print the path if keyword is exist in file.
sub printFile {
   my $element = $_;

   if(-f $element && $element =~ /\.*$/){ 

      open my $in, "<", $element or die $!;
      while(<$in>) {
         if (/\Q$searchString\E/) {
            my $last_update_time = (stat($element))[9];
            my $timestamp  = localtime($last_update_time);
            print $out "$File::Find::name". "     $timestamp". "     $searchString\n";
            last;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
print FH "$intfSplit ". "ended at ".(localtime)."\n";         #write the log file
```

everything is running fine but its running for very long time for single keyword search also.
can anyone please suggest some better way to improve the performance.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What timing and instrumentation have you done? The first step in any effort to improve perfomance is to measure current performance.

Comment: @MartinSkøtt is entirely correct. You need to figure out what bit is actually slow before you can make any meaningful optimisations - otherwise you're just guessing, and that might succeed but it's unlikely to take you as far as you can. Generally with parallel problems the things to examine are whether you're using the right amount of parallelism (time to start children vs. processing time vs. available parallel resource on the system) and whether the children are competing for the same resources in a way which reduces their parallelism.

Comment: You are reading your `intfSplitList.txt` twice just to count the lines. That's not a performance-killer, but it's unnecessary. Also I believe that all your processes will overwrite each others' log files as they all open the same file for reading, not appending. You should use a log file for each of them and merge them later. You can do that by simply adding a timestamp with microseconds, then concating all the files together and doing a sort on the timestamp. There are more things that could be optimised here, but I agree with the others. Figure out what's slow. Check out Devel::NYTProf.

Comment: I heard something about binary search in perl. I am not sure if we can use it here or not. Can anyone knows if it is possible to use binary search in this case to improve performance??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple instances of Perl adds a lot of unnecessary overhead.  Have you looked at [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586742/1919238), which suggested changing this?

Also as I mentioned previously, you have some unnecessary repetition here: there is no reason to open and process your search keyword file multiple times.  You can make one sub that opens the keyword file and puts the keywords in an array.  Then pass these keywords to another sub that does the searching.

You can make a search for multiple keywords much faster by searching for them all at once. Do something like this to get your keywords:

```
my @keywords = map {chomp;$_} <$fh>;
my $regex = "(" . join('|', map {quotemeta} @keywords) . ")";
```

Now you have a single regex like this: `(\Qkeyword1\E|\Qkeyword2\E)`.  You only have to search the files once, and if you want to see which keyword matched, just check the content of `$1`.  This won't speed things up for a single keyword, but searching for many keywords will be nearly as fast as searching for a single one.

Ultimately, though, if you are searching a huge directory structure on the network, there may be a limit to how much you can speed things up.

**Update:** corrected the chomping.  Thanks amon.

Comment: The return value of `chomp` is the number of chars removed, or something horrid like that. `map {chomp; $_} <$fh>` works better, in my experience.

Comment: @amon, thanks for catching that. I have made that particular stupid mistake many times! (I wish `chomp` did what I expected, though. I think in this case it is breaking the Perl rule of return values: "In general they do what you want".  Who ever cared how many characters chomp removed?)

Comment: @dan1111 thanks. I used regex here for multiple keyword search and its working expected. But I have one more question, I heard about binary search in perl. Can we use it here for better performance??

Comment: @Dhiraj, binary search isn't appropriate for this situation.  First of all, it requires random access, and a text file doesn't allow this (generally speaking). Secondly, binary search requires sorted data.  Thirdly, it doesn't work when you are searching for a subset of a string, which could appear anywhere in each line. Your problem by its very nature requires you to search all of the file.