# How to search multiple keywords in a directory in perl

Tags: performance, perl, search, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am facing big problem in performance . I have to search for the keyword inside the files present in a huge directory (30 gb) having around 600 sub-directories(which will again have many sub directories inside).

Currently i am spliting the sub-directory in to 50 text files, so each file will get 12 sub directory names and running all the 50 process paralley .

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($lines);

# Forks and returns the pid for the child:
my $pid = $pm->start and next;

# we are now in the child process
ucm5 ("-iinput.txt","-f$data"); - here $data will be text file names(text1,text2...text50)
--input.txt will have the multiple search keywords(hi , hello)

$pm->finish; # Terminates the child process

#!/usr/bin/perl
sub ucm5 {
local @ARGV = @_;
use strict;
use warnings;  
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Std;
#getting the input parameters
getopts('i:f:');

our($opt_i, $opt_f);
my $searchKeyword = $opt_i;                               #Search keyword file.
my $intfSplit = $opt_f;                               #split file
my $path = "C:/";                           #source directory
my $searchString;                                   #search keyword

open FH, ">>log.txt";                                          #open the log file to write

print FH "$intfSplit ". "started at ".(localtime)."\n";       #write the log file

open (FILE,$intfSplit);                                       #open the split file to read

while(<FILE>){

   my $intf= $_;                                              #setting the interface to intf
   chomp($intf);
   my $dir = $path.$intf;
   chomp($dir);
   print "$dir \n";                                              
   open(INP,$searchKeyword);                                  #open the search keyword file to read

   while (<INP>){      

   $searchString =$_;                                         #setting the search keyword to string
   chomp($searchString);
   print "$searchString \n";
   #open my $out, ">", "vob$intfSplit.txt" or die $!;          #open the vobintfSplit_* file to write
   open my $out, ">", "vob$intfSplit.txt" or die $!;
#calling subroutine printFile to find and print the path of element


#the subroutine will search for the keyword and print the path if keyword is exist in file.
my $printFile = sub {
   my $element = $_;

   if(-f $element && $element =~ /\.*$/){ 

      open my $in, "<", $element or die $!;
      while(<$in>) {
         if (/\Q$searchString\E/) {
            my $last_update_time = (stat($element))[9];
            my $timestamp  = localtime($last_update_time);
            print $out "$File::Find::name". "     $element"."     $timestamp". "     $searchString\n";
            last;
          }
        }
      }
    };
find(\&$printFile,$dir);  
  }
}
print FH "$intfSplit ". "ended at ".(localtime)."\n";         #write the log file
}
1;
```

Code may be little bit confuse i will explain what it is doing - in first while loop it opensthe text file which contain the sub-directories and inside that another while loop opens the textfile which contains the search words(hi,hello). inside that file::find will be called to search the keywords in the sub dorectories.

Now what happening is it is going into first sub directorie and searching for first keyword (HI) and once done it is again going for the same directory and searching for next keyword(Hello) which means reading the same directory twice .

but i want to search for both the keywords in the first reading time itself which will save lot of time . my output should have the path, filename , searchword .

example

C:/aims/if/sp/abcd.sql   abcd.sql   HI

C:/aims/if/sp/abcd.sql   abcd.sql   Hello

please help me in this issue . is there any other better way to search all the 600 sub directories with multiple keywords apart from parallel processing and thread.

Comment: I am guessing your bottle neck is going to be reading from harddisk.. If so, unless you have a RAID setup, parallelisation might actually slow things down.

Comment: Try taking a look at the responses to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643785/how-to-improve-perl-script-performance) which looks **very** similar yours

Comment: Take a look at this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2014/03/searching-multiple-strings-in-multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to just match all the keywords in one go so you just scan the files once.

The code below will look for "hello" or "test" and print any matching lines in input. Probably worth considering if you want to use quotemeta() on your keywords to prevent regex patterns being embedded in your words

```
while (<>) {
    if (/\b(hello|test)\b/i) { print "$1: $_" }
}
```

The \b matches a word-boundary (so it won't match "testing") and /i makes the whole test case insensitive. The matched word end ups in $1.

---

EDIT: fuller example showing how to process multiple matches.

Let's say we have a sample file /tmp/test.txt and a perl script match.pl (which only handles a single file in my example).

The test data:

```
This is a test
Line two
And this is line three
```

The script:

```
#!perl
use v5.10;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
my $contents = read_file('/tmp/test.txt');

my @raw_matches = $contents =~ /(test|line)/gi;

my %match_counts;
foreach (@raw_matches) {
    $match_counts{ lc($_) }++;
}

my @unique_matches = sort keys %match_counts;
foreach (@unique_matches) {
    say "$_ : count = $match_counts{$_}";
}
```

Sample output:

```
line : count = 2
test : count = 1
```

Now, this does rely on being able to read the whole file into memory in your script, but you didn't mention any huge files, just a lot of them to process. There may be slightly shorter ways to word the above example, but hopefully it's clear what each part is doing.

It should be simple enough to make the above into a function you can call once per file.

Comment: I tried your approach but the problem is if the same file consits of both the key words it is displaying only once it is not searching for the next keyword in the file . if we remove last(it will break the loop if the keyword is matched in the file) from the code then it is showing all the occurence of the keyword in the file including the result for the next keyword.